cursor is only showing "pointer" for the bottom half of my button in my Electron and React app
I am making an app using Electron and React. I am rendering a button that will be used for closing the window, and the button has a svg image in the middle, and the button is located in the header. However, when I hover my mouse over the button the cursor shows "pointer" for the bottom half, while for the top half it shows the default cursor.
I tried wrapping the button around a div and manually making the cursor change to "pointer" when hovered, but it didn't work. I also checked the element with devTools and it seems to be normal. I also tried putting a div outside the header and manually setting the cursor to "pointer" but that didn't work either. I also tried to change the height, but instead it just extended the region where the cursor turns into "pointer" down instead of up.
Below is my welcome.tsx (the page that has the problem):
import icon from '../../../assets/lemonide-full.png';
import closeIcon from '../../../assets/icons/close-light.svg';
import '../tailwind.css';
import './welcome.css';

const closeWindow = () => {
  window.electron.ipcRenderer.sendMessage('ipc', ['closeWindow']);
};

function Welcome() {
  return (
    <body className="h-screen bg-zinc-700">
      <header className="min-w-full h-12">
        <div className="relative top-1 right-1 float-right" id="closeBtn">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="flex justify-center w-10 h-10"
            onClick={closeWindow}
            id="closeBtn"
          >
            <img
              src={closeIcon}
              alt="close"
              className="flex justify-center py-2"
              id="closeBtn"
            />
          </button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div>
        <center>
          <img
            src={icon}
            alt="lemonide icon"
            width="500vh"
            height="300vh"
            className="flex justify-center"
            draggable="false"
          />
        </center>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}

export default Welcome;


welcome.css:
header {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

button {
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
  cursor: default;
}

#closeBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


how can i fix this?
